# Delete item from list if it is zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If any item in the "ju" list is equal to zero, it must be deleted and also the element of the same index in the "ja" list. For example if "a == 0" you must delete "a" from "ju" and "500" from "ja". I also want to have my program as short as possible.

```
milista1=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]
milista2=[500,200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1]
for y,z in zip(milista1 ,milista2):
    print('Hay {0} billete(s) de {1}'.format(y,z))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any item in the "ju" list is equal to zero, it must be deleted and also the element of the same index in the "ja" list. For example if "a == 0" you must delete "a" from "ju" and "500" from "ja". I also want to have my program as short as possible.

```
newlist1 = []
newlist2 = []

for i in range(0, len(milista1)):
    if milista1[i] != '0':
        newlist1.append(milista1[i])
        newlist2.append(milista2[i])

print (newlist1)
print (newlist2)
```